# Databricks Workflows: tasks of type 'Delta Live Tables pipeline' fail to retry

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a DLT pipeline and I want to be able to call it from different workflows. I understand that when an update is already in progress the 'Delta Live Tables pipeline' task will fail. However, I expect it to retry again following the retries parameters when setting up the tasks.

[Job config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPMn4.png)

[DLT task run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Eqp.png)

As you can see in the screenshots, the task is configured to retry twice with 1 min delay but the task run only once.